# Extra gap above and below banner in Slider Revolution

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, banner, responsive-images, slider-revolution

A website I am setting up on Wordpress, has Slider Revolution banner on the Home Page. I did set everything as required. Had put image layers for showing different layers in Desktop and Mobile. On Desktop the banners are showing full screen and proper height but in mobile even if the image size is proper, it is showing big blank space above and below the banner.

[image: This is the screenshot of the issue.]

[image: This is the screenshot of the layout settings]

[image: This is the screenshot of Mobile Banner Image Size]

My website link is [sanchetitoddlers.com](https://sanchetitoddlers.com/)

I tried different settings from last few days. Increasing Banner image height is not a option as the image already has more height for a mobile banner image. Not getting proper solution for this.

Please help me in solving this issue.